# NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined when runing LSTM prediction Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm trying to run the following line of code in python 3

predictions = lstm.predict_sequences_multiple(model,X_test, 50, 50)
lstm.plot_results_multiple(predictions, y_test, 50)

but I get the following error

[image]

NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

I've tried to use the following hacks

import sys
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    range = xrange

and this one too

try:
    xrange = xrange
except NameError:
    xrange = range

but still having the same problem, could somebody please help me out to find the solutions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just run that in Python 2 or modify `lstm.py` to use `range`.

You could also use your "hacks", but *inside* `lstm.py`:

```
try:
    xrange
except:
    xrange = range
```